# Finding the position of words in a sentence and populate in a specified format in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to get the position of word from a sentence by creating a new column(word name)
and writing the position number corresponding to the sentence in new column created.

I can get the position of the words using 'regexpr' but i don`t know how to bring it in required format.

```
  Example:

     text <- c("Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom.","When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day",
      "Sam broke his guitar")

     words <- c("Sam","guitar","raining")


  Expected output format:

  **text**                                                             **Sam**       **guitar**          **raining**

  Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom.            1              39                 -1

  When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day                      19             -1                 11

  Sam broke his guitar                                                    1              15                 -1
```

I understand, if words are not found in a sentence, 'regexpr' will give as -1. Can anyone please help me to get the output in above desired format?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
res<- matrix(nrow=length(text),ncol=length(words))
rownames(res) <- text
colnames(res) <- words
for (i in 1:length(words)){
  res[,i]=regexpr(words[i],text)
}

res


                                                             Sam guitar raining
Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom.   1     39      -1
When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day            19     -1      11
Sam broke his guitar                                           1     15      -1
```

Comment: Thanks @GyB for your code. But in output(res), text is getting combined as one single text. There should be three different rows.

Comment: Are you sure your *text* variable has still 3 elements?

Comment: Thanks @GyB for your guidance. I got the output in the required format. Just we need to remove "[1:length(text)]" from 5th line of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sapply` with `gregexpr` as below:

```
sapply(words,function(x)gregexpr(x,text))
```

Output:

```
     Sam guitar raining
[1,] 1   39     -1     
[2,] 19  -1     11     
[3,] 1   15     -1
```

One liner for data.frame conversion:

```
df<-data.frame(cbind(text=text ,setNames(sapply(words,function(x)gregexpr(x,text)),c("Sam","guitar","raining"))))
```

Output:

```
    #                                                            text Sam guitar raining
    # 1 Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom.   1     39      -1
    # 2           When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day  19     -1      11
    # 3                                         Sam broke his guitar   1     15      -1
```

Comment: Thanks @PKr for suggesting in another way to solve my problem. It is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i would try something like this:
Hi i edited the code so that the output is the way you need it.

```
text <- ("Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom. When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day. Sam broke his guitar")
words <- c("Sam","guitar","raining")

sentences <- strsplit(text,'\\. ')[[1]]
my_output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(words),nrow=length(sentences)))
colnames(my_output) <- words
rownames(my_output) <- sentences
my_output

for(j in 1:nrow(my_output)){
for(i in 1:length(sentences)){
  appears <-which(strsplit(sentences[i], split=" ")[[1]] == words[j])
  if(length(appears)>0){
  my_output[i,j] <- appears
  }else{
  my_output[i,j] <- 'NA'  
  }
}
}
my_output
```

The ouput now looks like this:

```
                                                            Sam guitar raining
Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom   1      8      NA
When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day            4     NA       3
Sam broke his guitar                                          1      4      NA
```

I hope thats what you wanted :-)

Comment: Thanks @Joyvalley. Your output format is different. My main requirement is to populate it in specified format.

Comment: Hi off course i used print for output which is not really usefull if you want to store the data. i thougth the output format wasnt the important part. I can easily change it to your ouput format or similar if you want me to.

Comment: Hi - Your code is throwing error. My text variable has 3 different elements. But in your code, you have  combined all the 3 elements in one. I guess this is the reason behind the error.

Comment: hmm .. if i copy and paste the code right from here it works fine.

Comment: Yes, now your code is running without any error. But the output is wrong. Please see the output of mine(question area), or of PKr and GyB.

Comment: Please accept my apology. Your output shows the position of the word in the sentence. I missed it. Your way is also correct and solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit messy, but will also handle if the same word repeats more than once.

```
text <- c("Sam can often be found practicing his guitar in his bedroom.",
          "When it's raining Sam will often stay home all day",
          "Sam broke his guitar", 
          "Sam raining guitar Sam raining guitar")

words <- c("Sam","guitar","raining")

df <- data.frame(text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(words))
{
  word.locations <- gsub(")","",gsub("c(","",unlist(paste(gregexpr(pattern = words[i], df$text))), fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
  df <- cbind(df,word.locations)
}

colnames(df) <- c("text", words)
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt Jewett for suggesting me another way. It is useful.